# Code does not work in published version

Tags: asp.net, iis, webdeploy

I am new to ASP.NET web application deployment so this might seem like a noob question.

I have created an application using ASP.NET 4.5. Previously when I performed final testing, I used to copy my source code to IIS 8 (without publishing) and then test the app. All of the code worked perfectly.

Now I have started publishing my ASP.NET web app properly to IIS. The problem is, some of my code is now not working. For example, an upload control is not being able to upload file. The same code works perfectly in the unpublished version.

Since my app is published, I cannot debug the problem.

Comment: You can still debug dlls remotely provided you have the pdb files in the same place (eg bin folder). There are several things which can catch you out in this scenario. Is this your local IIS? Have you given sufficient access rights to your app pool account?

Comment: i suggest using ELMAH or Glimpse to trace error on publish website and proceed accordingly.seems like permissions issue.